# How to align one vertical image with another 2 vertical images in block

Tags: html, css, image, positioning

I am trying to align these 3 images, and i have run out of ideas. The blue and orange images don't align at the bottom, it happens with default container width as well as when you squeeze the browser window.

Original size of the blue image is 925 x 1280, green and orange 1280 x 853.
One of my ideas is that images resolution is a problem itself, is it possible?

It's just a small part of the page, so I don't want to use grid, because it would interrupt the whole responsiveness mechanics i think.

```css
.container {
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.images {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.right {
    width: 50%;
    float:right;

}
.right img {
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
.left {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="images">
            <img src="blue.jpg" class="left">
            <div class="right">
                <img src="green.jpg">
                <img src="orange.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: why do you think that `grid` would interrupt the whole responsiveness mechanics ??

Comment: Okay, I've figured how to do the same thing with a grid, I was wrong about responsiveness, it works correctly, but the problem remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fix images height and make:

right image height = 1/2 left image height.

Example:

```
.images > img {
      height: 400px; // left image height;
    }
.right img {
      height: 200px; // tight images height;
    }
```

To avoid stretching images you should remove: `width: 100%` from right images and add  `width: auto` to left image.

You'll end up with expected result but with more spaces between images because of resolutions of images.

```css
  .container {
        max-width: 1100px;
        margin: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .images {
        position: relative;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .images > img {
        height: 400px;
        width: auto;
      }
      

      .right {
        width: 50%;
        float: right;
      }
      .right img {
        padding: 10px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: block;
        height: 200px;
      }
      .left {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 50%;
        padding: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
      }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="images">
          <img src="http://ejad.solutions/cloud/left.jpg" class="left" />
          <div class="right">
            <img src="http://ejad.solutions/cloud/right1.jpg" />
            <img src="http://ejad.solutions/cloud/right2.jpg" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

To remove spaces between right and left edit `.right` and make it:

```
   .right {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please put all the 3 images in one div the use on the div as shown below :

`text-align : block;`

Comment: It will just put all the images in a block position, I want one image on the left and two images combined vertically on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Are you avoiding using display:flex?

```
<div class="container">
 <div id="bigimage"><img src="BIGIMAGE"></div>
 <div class="smallcontainer">
  <div id="smallleft"><img src="smallerleft"></div>
  <div id="smallright><img src="smallerright"></div>
  </div>
</div>

.container{
width: /*same width as big image*/;
}
#bigimage{
width:100%;
}
.smallcontainer{
width: /*same width as bigimage*/;
}
#smallleft{
width:50%;
}
#smallright{
width:50%;
}
```

somthing like this?

also you'll have to set the height of the 2 bottom images if you want them flush, but that would scale them funny. I would just resize in photoshop tbh.

Comment: Not exactly, I want one image on the left side with width: 50% and height 100% of a given area X, and on the right side i want two images in block, each one of them with 50% width and 50% height of the X area

Answer (score 0):

Why not try to use Flex.

Change the container display to Flex, Flex direction to Column and it should work...